# Bind Polyline from MVVM Googlemap Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

After getting position from Google map Api and looking to create polyline between two points but problem is Polyline->GeoPath is readonly.
How to assign Positions to GeoPath or bind position directly to map?

I am using following [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/polygons)

```
Map map = new Map
{
// ...
};
// instantiate a polyline
Polyline polyline = new Polyline
{
StrokeColor = Color.Blue,
StrokeWidth = 12,
Geopath =
{
new Position(47.6381401, -122.1317367),
new Position(47.6381473, -122.1350841),
new Position(47.6382847, -122.1353094),
new Position(47.6384582, -122.1354703),
new Position(47.6401136, -122.1360819),
new Position(47.6403883, -122.1364681),
new Position(47.6407426, -122.1377019),
new Position(47.6412558, -122.1404056),
new Position(47.6414148, -122.1418647),
new Position(47.6414654, -122.1432702)
}
};

// add the polyline to the map's MapElements collection
map.MapElements.Add(polyline);
```

Comment: you can add items to the Geopath collection, you just can't assign a new instance of Geopath

Comment: @Jason already have IList<Position> but how to Bind it with Map ? Please explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polyline -> Geopath -> Add will solve the issue

```
Polyline polyline = new Polyline
{
StrokeColor = Color.Blue,
StrokeWidth = 12
}
polyline.GeoPath.Add(new Position)
```